# Blazor how to SaveFileDialog?

Tags: download, blazor, blazor-server-side

How to save a stream in Blazor? 
I.e. I read stream (AWS S3 object) and want to save it as a pdf file on user's local disk. How to select folder?
Something like SaveFileDialog

Comment: Server or WASM ? What local disk, server or client ?

Comment: Server-side. User needs to save the object to his local disk

Comment: Just add a link to the file on your UI and let the browser to its job.

Comment: You cannot access the local file system from a web application.

Comment: @aguafrommars, I need to save a S3 object to a file. It can be downloaded as a stream. Thats why I need to ask user 'Save as'

Comment: Create a wrapper API on your server returning the S3 object as a file then

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate signed or not signed Url request string
2. Add 
   Download

It opens the new tab with file content. Then user can view or download the file.
Thnx @agua-from-mars